# If a tensor's shape defines how many entitites are in each dimension, can a tensor's shape have a different number of entities for each dimension?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensor

I'm following a few tutorials to gain an understanding of tensors in TensorFlow.  I understand that rank specifies the number of dimensions a tensor is.  Now I'm curious about the term 'shapes' and I want to know if its possible or common to have one dimension with more entities than the next dimension or will the number of elements always be equal across dimensions?

I hope this makes sense and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand your question correctly but I'll try to answer anyway, only if to provide some clarity.

A tensor represents simply an N-dimensional array. A shape of the tensor is a list of the sizes along the given dimension and the rank is the number of dimensions.

So take for example a 3D array of size `10x20x5`. Then the shape is `(10, 20, 5)` and the rank is `3`, the total number of elements of such array is `10*20*5=1000`.

Comment: this definitely helps.  So are you saying that the shape is defined by all of the elements in this 3D array?  I was probably over analyzing it because I was thinking that in a 3D array, the first dimension of this array may have more entities than the second dimension of this this same 3D array.  Was I looking at it incorrectly?

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean now. You are not talking about dimensions but slices of the array. Let's say you have the 3D array. Then `array[0]` would be a 2D array containing all the elements in the first slice, `array[1]` would be another 2D array containing the second slice, etc. In that case, the answer to your question is no, the shape is static, so every slice, no matter over which dimension, has a defined shape. In the example, every slice over the first dimension (e.g. `array[0]`) will always have a shape of `(20, 5)`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Another way to look at this is that 1D array is a list of elements. A 2D array would be a list of lists of elements. A 3D array would be a list of lists of lists of elements. You get the idea. And in TensorFlow, all these lists have their dimensions fixed and defined by the tensor shape. So the 2D tensor will always be a rectangular matrix and a 3D tensor will always be a cuboid matrix, etc.